# Why does node server.js work, but node ./backend/server.js give me this error?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I currently have the following file directories:
[image: File directory]

and if i do node server.js while in the backend directory, the server runs. However, if I am in the root directory, and do node ./backend/server.js, the following error shows up:

[image: uri error]

Here is my code for the mongodb server on server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: true,credentials: true}));
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.port || 5000;

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})
```

Comment: Log your `uri` variable before the `mongoose.connect` and check if that's a valid uri. I think that is what causing the error as the first parameter of the `mongoose.connect` must be a uri string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it is because your `.env` file is not in the root.

**Explanation:**

When you run `node server.js` you application looks for `.env` file and load environment variables. But, when you navigate to root and run `node ./backend/server.js` it can't find `.env` file. So `process.env.ATLAS_URI` is `undefined`.